# Rails, Thinreports, table with group by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, report

I am trying to use thinreports to produce a list/table that is separated into groups by year each with it's own header. Is that posssible? I have the feeling it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your question mean the following URL?
https://github.com/hidakatsuya/thinreports-list-group